# How does SQLServer lock rows based on query WHERE clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

They are two sql session

session 1 start first

```
update table1
set status = 3
where status = 2
```

session 2 start second, but session 1 stil running

```
update table1
set status = 4
where status = 2
```

session 1 and 2 finish

Is possible, that one records will be status 3 and another status 4 ? Or always updated record will be status 3 ?
Sql engine first lock all rows who pass where clause, and another statement have to acquire lock, or record is locked when it is read?
In another words is set lock on where clause and another statement have to acquire lock on this where clause?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, but I'm guessing that you're asking about multi-write consistency? You'd want to use transactions in that case.

Comment: Its likely that session 1 will lock the rows/pages/table until it is complete, only then will session 2 be allowed to carry on.

Answer (score 1):

This is too long for a comment.

You should read the documentation that SQL Server provides on locking and transactions.  [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj856598%28v=sql.110%29.aspx) it is.

Under normal circumstances, databases are ACID-compliant for their transactions.  In SQL Server, each update statement is a transaction, so it either completes or does not.  Hence, I would expect that under normal circumstances, SQL Server would set all the values to either 3 or all to 4, but not both.

The semantics of transactions are then complicated by the real world and, in particular, different locking schemes.  So, you can set parameters to allow for dirty writes, for instance.  This is why I'm pointing you to the documentation.  There is a basic principle of ACID-ness; beyond that, there are a lot of database specifics.